# load a wordpress page into another wordpress page using iframe

Tags: php, iframe

I've looked around in StackExchange & elsewhere before asking my question directly:

I have created a Wordpress custom template which users can add job-vacancy posts to.

I want to display these posts as part of front-page.php in the same website _ I think the best way to do this would be an iframe format but I have read that, for security reasons, Wordpress negates `<iframe></iframe>`

Is there a way to achieve this effect without using a Wordpress plug-in?
and what would the dynamic code be inside the iframe `src` element?

Thanks in advance for any pointers

Comment: If you created a job-vacancy posts section in Wordpress site, presumably with [custom post types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types), within `front-page.php` you can use [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to retrieve your posts, run a loop and display them. If that doesn't sound right, please expand as to how you initially setup these posts you want to display.

Comment: I had thought to use a custom page rather than custom posts David, though now you have mentioned get_posts() option, I can see that would probably be an easier solution _ Many thanks for your input

Comment: custom page? you mean a normal Wordpress page? If thats the case: you're after getting `post_content` from one page on another. Say the ID of the source page was `42`. Within the destination `front-page.php` file, you could do something like: `echo apply_filter('the_content',get_post(42)->post_content);`

Comment: or "custom page" being custom coded php page? If thats the case then you need to think about code reusability - wrapping the data of the custom page in a function(s), then putting those function in `functions.php`, then using said functions it both your "custom page" and on the `front-page.php`. (forgive the peppering of posts - I'm trying to grasp the problem without seeing what this 'custom template  job-vacancy posts' page is or how its coded)

Comment: i really appreciate your input David! : ) To be honest i'm just trying to make things as simple as possible for my client _ I'm fairly certain the easiest method will be getting them to add a category to the post then simply displaying that, as per your first suggestion _ I got locked into the iframe idea and the posts solution evaded me _ Thanks again